# Cast from [SKNode]! to unrelated type 'xxx' always fails, Swift after upgrade to 1.2

Tags: ios, swift

I upgraded my Project to Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3) and got tones of errors.

Since my project based on Cordova, I have a lot of JSON parse.

From Javascript I try to parese following object:

```
{
    search: searchString,
    limit: 50
}
```

*code snippets:*

```
func getJsonArgs(command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand, name:String) -> AnyObject{

        var obj:AnyObject = command.arguments[0] as AnyObject!
        var theData:AnyObject = obj[name] as AnyObject!
        return theData
    }

var obj:AnyObject = self.getJsonArgs(command, name: "getContacts")

var search:String = obj["search"] as AnyObject! as? String ?? "" // OK
var limit:Int = obj["limit"] as? Int ?? 0 // Cast from [SKNode]! to unrelated type 'Int' always fails
```

How can I properly and safety fetch `search` and `limit` values?

In `search` case why do I need 1st downcast `[SKNode]` to `AnyObject` and only after to `String`? It seems so messy.

Thanks,

Comment: You are trying to cast an array of `SKNode`s to an  `Int`?  Why do you expect that to ever work?

Comment: @NobodyNada not at all. `obj:AnyObject` has key-value structure and It worked in Xcode 6.1. I have no clue why I got this error

Comment: What is the `SKNode`?

Comment: @NobodyNada have no idea. This is what compiler tells me

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding.

Comment: @NobodyNada I did a lot of times and got about 200 similar errors over my project

Comment: `SKNode` is from SpriteKit. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html Can you post more code? It's unclear what `obj` does contain, what `self.getJsonArgs` does, ... `as? String` should work, `as? Int` should work for `Int` and `NSNumber`, ... https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13929547/Screenshots/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-20%20at%200.24.32.png

Comment: @RobertVojta posted `getJsonArgs` method

Comment: One thing that would probably help is to use actual types instead of just `AnyObject` everywhere.

Comment: Also, does your project even `import SpriteKit` anywhere?